# How to find the index of an element in a list?

Tags: haskell

Giving an element in a list, which function can I use to find its index?

For instance, I want to find the index of 3 in the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Which function exists in Haskell that I can use for this?

Comment: If you need the index of an element in a list you're not thinking in Haskell yet.  Haskell lists are more like streams of elements.  You wouldn't ask C++ for the index of an element in stdin would you?  You probably want a finite length data structure such as Data.Vector.

Comment: Does your question also apply to the more general case of the list being, say, `[1,2,3,4,3]`? That is, would your desired function return both of those indexes, or maybe just the first one it found?

Comment: @JasonDagit I don't think it is true. E.g. I'm doing an implementation of a database *(part of a student project)*, and there is a header of a table with column names, and a list of rows with according values. Given a key, the only way I see, is to find an index in header, and take according to the index values from every row.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Take a look here:

- [Finding index of element in a list in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496980/finding-index-of-element-in-a-list-in-haskell)

i.e. use `elemIndex` from `Data.List`:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3AelemIndex

```
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
```

Comment: Note that `elemIndex` returns type `Maybe Int`, so you can "extract" the value like this: `fromJust $ elemIndex 3 [1,2,3,4]` (import `Data.Maybe`)

Comment: `fromJust` may throw an error. You can use [`fromMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) to provide a default value in case the list doesn't contain the element : `fromMaybe (-1) $ elemIndex 3 [1,2,3,4]`