# Learning Haskell maps, folds, loops and recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, functional-programming

I've only just dipped my toe in the world of Haskell as part of my journey of programming enlightenment (moving on from, procedural to OOP to concurrent to now functional).

I've been trying an online [Haskell Evaluator](http://tryhaskell.org/).

However I'm now stuck on a problem:

**Create a simple function that gives the total sum of an array of numbers.**

In a procedural language this for me is easy enough (using recursion) (c#) :

```
private int sum(ArrayList x, int i)
{
  if (!(x.Count < i + 1)) {
        int t = 0;

        t = x.Item(i);
        t = sum(x, i + 1) + t;
        return t;
    }
}
```

All very fine however my failed attempt at Haskell was thus:

```
let sum x = x+sum  in map sum [1..10]
```

this resulted in the following error (from that above mentioned website):

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = a -> t
```

Please bear in mind I've only used Haskell for the last 30 minutes!

I'm not looking simply for an answer but a more explanation of it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I'm not looking simply for an answer but a more explanation of it.

On the left-hand side of the = you use `sum` as a function applied to `x`.  The compiler doesn't know the type of `x`, so the compiler uses type variable `a` to stand for "the type of `x`."  At thus point the compiler doesn't know the result type of the function `sum` either, so it picks another type variable, this type `t`, to stand for the result type.  Now on the left-hand side the compiler thinks that the type of `x` is `a -> t` (function accepting `a` and returning `t`).

On the right-hand side of the = you add `x` and `sum`.  In Haskell all kinds of numbers can be added, but you can add two numbers only if they have the *same* type.  So here the compiler assumes that `sum` has the same type as `x`, namely type `a`.

But in Haskell an identifier has one type—maybe a whangdilly complicated type, but one type nevertheless.  This includes `sum`, whose type should be the same on both sides of the ` sign, so the compiler tries to solve the equation

```
a = a -> t
```

**There are no values for `a` and `t` that solve this equation.**  It simply can't be done.  There is no `a` such that `a` is equal to a function that accepts itself as an argument.  Thus ariseth the error message

```
cannot construct the infinite type: a = a -> t
```

Even with all the explanation, it's not such a great error message, is it?

Welcome to Haskell :-)

---

P.S. You might enjoy trying "Helium, for learning Haskell", which gives much nicer error messages for  beginners.

Comment: This was the comprehensive explanation I was looking for. After reading this and doing further reading I now understand it a little better.

Answer (score 12):

'sum' takes a list of values and reduces it to a single value. You can either write it as an explicit loop (remember that Haskell has no loop keywords, but uses recursion). Note how the definition has two parts, based on the shape of the list:

```
mysum []     = 0
mysum (x:xs) = x + mysum xs
```

Or more efficiently, in a [tail-recursive](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Preliminaries#Tail_Recursion) style:

```
mysum xs = go 0 xs
   where
      go n []     = n
      go n (x:xs) = go (n+x) xs
```

However, Haskell has a rich library of control structures that operate on lazy lists. In this case, *reduction* of a list to a single value can be done with a reduce function: a fold.

So mysum can be written as:

```
mysum xs  = foldr (+) 0 xs
```

For example:

```
Prelude> foldr (+) 0 [1..10]
55
```

Your mistake was to use a *map*, which transforms a list, one element at a time, rather than a *fold*.

I'd suggest you start with an introduction to Haskell, perhaps "[Programming in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/book.html)", to get a feel for the core concepts of functional programming. Other good introductory materials are described [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/how-to-learn-haskell)

Comment: I'm not sure what the significance of the 0 plays, can you expand on the use of the zero please?

Comment: The 0 is the initial value for the accumulating parameter in the fold. It is the 't' value in the original source.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read a good tutorial, there are a number of big misunderstandings.

First I'm going to assume you mean lists and not arrays. Arrays exist in Haskell, but they aren't something you'd encounter at the beginner level. (Not to mention you're using [1..10] which is a list of the numbers 1 to 10).

The function you want is actually built in, and called sum, so we'll have to call our something else, new_sum:

```
new_sum [] = 0
new_sum (h:t) = h + (sum t)
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't try the code and check my types (bad me). fixed.

Comment: it was the (sum t) part that I had difficulty in understanding, but after Norman's answer and further reading this now makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the first part of this:

```
let sum x = x+sum
```

What would the type of sum be in this case? It takes a number and returns a function that takes a number which returns a function that takes a number etc.  if you had written it
let sum x = + x 
you would have a function that takes a number and returns the function +x.
and 
let sum = +
 would return a function that takes two integers and adds them.

so now let's look at the second part.
 in map sum [1..10] 
 map takes a function of one argument and applies it to every element of the list.  There is no room to wedge an accumulator in there, so let's look at other list functions in particular foldl, foldr. both of these take a function of two arguments a list and a beginning value.  The difference between foldl and foldr is on the side in which they start. l being left so 1 + 2 + 3 etc and r being right 10 + 9 + 8 etc.

let sum = (+) in foldl sum 0 [1..10]