# Simple haskell unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, haskell

I want to go through [99 Haskell Problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10), and I want to concentrate on the solution but with testing. If I have the solution to the first problem as a 3 line `.hs` file,

```
myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast [x] = x
myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs
```

What is the minimal amount of code I can add to this so that I can add tests inline and run them with `runhaskell`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) (which basicaly generates test inputs for you) is probably the best way to test pure function. And if a function in question has an analog from the standard library you can just test your function using the standard one as a model:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.All

myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast [x] = x
myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs

-- here we specify that 'myLast' should return exactly the same result
-- as 'last' for any given 'xs'
prop_myLast xs = myLast xs == last xs


return [] -- need this for GHC 7.8
-- quickCheckAll generates test cases for all 'prop_*' properties
main = $(quickCheckAll)
```

If you run it you'll get:

```
=== prop_myLast on tmp3.hs:12 ===
*** Failed! Exception: 'tmp3.hs:(7,1)-(8,25): Non-exhaustive patterns in function myLast' (after 1 test):  
[]
False
```

because your `myLast` doesn't handle `[]` case (it should but should probably throw an error like 'last').
But here we can simply adjust our test but specifying that only non-empty strings should be used (using `==>` combinator):

```
prop_myLast xs = length xs > 0 ==> myLast xs == last xs
```

Which makes all 100 auto-generated test cases to pass for `myLast`:

```
=== prop_myLast on tmp3.hs:11 ===
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
True
```

PS Another way to specify `myLast` behavior may be:

```
prop_myLast2 x xs = myLast (xs++[x]) == x
```

Or better:

```
prop_myLast3 x xs = x `notElem` xs ==> myLast (xs++[x]) == x
```

Comment: When I run my file with `runhaskell lists.hs` it gives me "lists.hs:44:8: parse error on input `$'" Is this how I'm supposed to run it? https://gist.github.com/923814

Comment: Try adding `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}` as per my example. If your `runhaskell` point to `runghc` this should do the trick. Also rename `prop_last'` to just `prop_last` - otherwise QuickCheck seems to ignore it.

Comment: So that all works (thanks!), but now how do I make quickcheck catch the errors? I added `last' [] = error "empty list"`

Comment: I ended up using the properties/filters for QuickCheck (as you said) since from my searching, I can't tell QuickCheck that it should expect an error, but only that it shouldn't run those.

Comment: This is a bit out of date. As noted in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28358874/1088108), GHC 7.8 requires a line with `return []` (or something else to break up TH processing) between the `prop_`s and the `quickCheckAll`.

Answer (score 2):

hspec is also a testing framework for Haskell, which is inspired by Ruby RSpec. It integrates with QuickCheck, SmallCheck, and HUnit.