# How to expect exceptions with QuickCheck2

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to pick up Haskell recently, but I am having some difficulty with QuickCheck2 (which I'm trying to learn while coding up the 99 problems). I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683911/simple-haskell-unit-testing) along with related ones on the matter.

Like OP from the aforementioned question, I'm interested in finding out whether it is possible for QuickCheck2 to expect exceptions. I know this is possible with QuickCheck 1. Some googling around led me to the following version of my code to test a `myLast` function which returns the last element of a list:

```
prop_myLast :: [Int] -> Bool
prop_myLast [] = expectFailure . myLast $ []
prop_myLast xs = myLast xs == last xs
```

Of course, this (1) does not typecheck, since `expectFailure` returns a `Property` and (2) requires an import from v1 of QuickCheck. Regarding (1) I don't really see how to make this work - I tried looking up how to catch exceptions on my own but was met with more difficulty because this started bringing in the `IO` monad. With respect to (2) I don't know if bringing in the `expectFailure` function is a good idea in the first place - could anyone experienced with the system tell me if I'm supposed to be using components from both v1 and v2? If not, where is the analogous `expectFailure` for v2 of QuickCheck?

Comment: You can change the type to `[Int] -> Property` and change the 2nd case to `property (myLast xs == last xs)`, or `myLast xs === last xs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `expectFailure` like this:

```
prop :: Int -> Bool
prop x = x + 1 == x  -- should always be False

main = quickCheck (expectFailure prop)
```

However, `expectFailure` only tests that there is at least one test case which fails - i.e. it really expects your code to fail. You want QuickCheck to ignore any failures in the event that it passes the empty list to `prop_myLast`.

One way to do this is with the `==>` operator:

```
prop_myLast :: [Int] -> Property
prop_myLast xs = not (null xs) ==> myLast xs == last xs
```

Another example:

```
prop_cubed :: Int -> Property
prop_cubed x = (x > 1) ==> x^3 > x   -- note: not true for negative values so don't
                                     --       test those cases
```

Quickcheck will discard generated test cases which do not match the conditional.

Update: One way of explicitly testing the `[]` case is:

```
quickCheck $ expectFailure $ seq (myLast []) True
```

The expression `seq a True` will return `True` unless `a` throws an exception or diverges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mind addressing the issue between using QuickCheck v1 and v2? Importing only `Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2` is insufficient (`expectFailure` and `Property` seem not to be visible). Do people work with both at the same time, or is there a solution for QuickCheck2 exclusively?

Comment: I have `QuickCheck-2.6` installed and importing `Test.QuickCheck` gives access to `expectFailure` and `Property` as well as `quickCheck`.

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that this was a deprecated module (pretty daring assumption, only made on the basis that it didn't have a 2 at the end), but based on your comment I think that it should be fine.

Comment: Actually, I still seem to be having this issue, which I would appreciate an answer for: compiling gives the following issue: `No instance for (Testable b0) arising from a use of `expectFailure'
    The type variable `b0' is ambiguous`, and changing `myLast` to `(myLast :: [Int] -> Int)` inline didn't seem to help (unlike what some of the SO answers on that topic seemed to indicate...).

Comment: [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/vlad17/581a1d9ee3b601602a8b), I trimmed off the imports - I'm also trying to do this with modules but I don't think that's causing the issues.

Comment: I responded to the gist.