# quickCheckAll always return "True"

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, quickcheck

I'm trying to use QuickCheck following [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5684078/4533286).
I test like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.All


last' :: [a] -> a
last' [x] = x
last' (_:xs) = last' xs

prop_test x = last' x == last x

check = do
        putStrLn "quickCheck"
        quickCheck (prop_test :: [Char]-> Bool)

check2 = do
        putStrLn "quickCheckAll"
        $quickCheckAll
```

Then I load it in winGHCI and call `check` and `check2`. I get

```
quickCheck
*** Failed! (after 1 test): 
Exception:
  list.hs:(7,1)-(8,23): Non-exhaustive patterns in function last'
""
```

which I think it's reasonable. However, I get this from `check2`

```
quickCheckAll
True
```

I'm confused because no matter how I change the `last'` function, even wrong, `quickCheckAll` always return True.

What's wrong with my code? How can I fix this?

Comment: For what it's worth, when I try, I get a warning, too: "Name prop_test found in source file but was not in scope" (with a line number pointing at the call to `quickCheckAll`). Very mysterious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [`Test.QuickCheck.All`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck-All.html) docs:

> To use `quickCheckAll`, add a definition to your module along the lines of
>
> ```
> return []
> runTests = $quickCheckAll
> ```
>
> and then execute `runTests`.
>
> Note: the bizarre `return []` in the example above is needed on GHC 7.8; without it, `quickCheckAll` will not be able to find any of the properties.

Adding `return []` before your `check` makes it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

To use quickCheckAll, you need a function which reads:

`return []
runTests = $quickCheckAll`

The other comment mentions this, but doesn't point out that it will still always return true unless the function is located below all of your quickCheck functions!