# Haskell/GHC 7.10.1/Leksah : What is the meaning of this Warning: "name ... found in source file but was not in scope"

Tags: haskell, leksah

I am using the Leksah IDE 0.15.0.1 and I get a warning when compiling the example package: "name ... found in source file but was not in scope".

What is the meaning of this Warning ?

I googled for this text but found noting enlightening.

[image]

Comment: Does it matter if you make a function declaration just above `prop_hello`? Something like `prop_hello :: String -> Bool`.

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358575/quickcheckall-always-return-true Or this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694097/haskell-compiler-error-not-in-scope

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably lies within the lines

```hs
testMain = do
    allPass <- $quickCheckAll
    unless allPass exitFailure
```

According to the [QuickCheck documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-All.html#v:quickCheckAll), in order to utilize quickCheckAll, the IO action that performs `$quickCheckAll` must have `return []` before its definition.

> To use quickCheckAll, add a definition to your module along the lines of
>
> ```
> return []
> runTests = $quickCheckAll
> ```
>
> and then execute runTests.

So applying it to your testMain definition, it would end up being

```hs
return []
testMain = do
    allPass <- $quickCheckAll
    unless allPass exitFailure
```

The documentation also provides an explanation for such need:

> Note: the bizarre `return []` in the example above is needed on GHC 7.8 and > later; without it, quickCheckAll will not be able to find any of the
> properties. For the curious, the `return []` is a Template Haskell
> splice that makes GHC insert the empty list of declarations at that
> point in the program; GHC typechecks everything before the `return []`
> before it starts on the rest of the module, which means that the later
> call to quickCheckAll can see everything that was defined before the
> `return []`. Yikes!