# where from to learn functional languages - haskell

Tags: haskell, resources, functional-programming

Functional Languages - I have heard about them a lot. A related thread  [Best Functional Language to start with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102911/whats-a-good-functional-language-to-learn-first)  recommends a learner to start with Haskell and subsequently grow his knowledge in the domain.

So I was thinking about starting to learn Haskell. Are there any better choices to start with? If not, Could you help me with some resources from where I can get a deep insight into the world of Haskell. I am a newbie to functional languages, and as such, I have no idea of what these are. Could you help me with some good e-books which is a recommended read for this topic?

Comment: Vote to close?? :-o Not constructive?? What does that mean?? Would have been better had it been flagged as an "exact duplicate"..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to learn Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/how-to-learn-haskell)

Comment: Once you get an answer, you cant delete your post!! Weird..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (book) is a good place to start with Haskell: http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Haskell is a good language to start functional programming because it a purely functional language. Later, you can look at multi-paradigm languages like F# ( especially if you are used to .NET)

Comment: [PDF](http://learnyouahaskell.com/learnyouahaskell.pdf)