# haskell subtract error

Tags: haskell

```
answerFalse::Int->IO()
answerFalse hp=do
            hp--
            if hp<=0 then
                putStrLn"================Game Over================"

            else
                print(hp)
```

i already declare hp as int with value 3
now my problem is when i put "hp--", it shows error

```
 Couldn't match expected type `IO a0' with actual type `Int'
```

but if i put "--hp", the result print is 3 not 2.

i also tried let hp=hp-1, the system stuck there.

Comment: Haskell is not C. You cannot simply go around changing the values of variables!

Comment: Haskell's a functional language, not an imperative one, so things like -- and ++ won't work.

Comment: I like it when things like `let hp = hp-1` sends the computer to eternal decrement hell.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This be a friendly place!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't modify variables in Haskell. `hp++` and `++hp` (or `hp--` and `--hp`) don't work in Haskell at all; the reason why `--hp` compiles is that `--` creates a comment which comments out the `hp` part.

What you are trying to do is this:

```
answerFalse hp =
  if hp - 1 <= 0
  then putStrLn "================Game Over================"
  else print hp
```

You can also do it like this, by creating a new variable:

```
answerFalse hp = do
  let newHp = hp - 1
  if newHp <= 0
    then putStrLn "================Game Over================"
    else print hp
```

You need to review your basic Haskell knowledge by reading beginner tutorials. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/how-to-learn-haskell) provides excellent resources for you.

Comment: thanks for the link and explaination, this is my first time to learn functional language. Thanks again!

Comment: and `hp--` introduces a comment *after* `hp`.  In the `do` context, `hp` is expected to have type `IO a0` where `a0` is some arbitrary type which does not matter, since the value is not bound.  However, `hp` has type `Int`, which leads to the error about not being able to match `IO a` with `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

things like i++ can be modelled in Haskell by using State monad. You can look examples on [haskellwiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad#Complete_and_Concrete_Example_1)