# beginning functional programming with haskell?

Tags: haskell

Please excuse my poor English ,i am new to programming in the past 6 months i have learned java and c and have been suggested to get exposed to functional programming, is haskell a suitable language for a beginner?

Comment: Suitable language for a `beginner`..? You have learnt C and Java. I doubt you are a beginner. Besides, if you want to learn functional programming go ahead with it. Otherwise don't.

Comment: let me rephrase the question ,will i have to learn many concepts before i become productive and is it transferable to other functional language , by the way thanks for the down vote

Comment: What does this even mean `will i have to learn many concepts before i become productive`.. ? Productive how..? You can setup a haskell dev environment and start coding right away. Productive is purely subjective. If you want to learn it.. LEARN IT. And become `productive`. You could have easily reached on haskell functions by now, instead of wasting your time by asking `unproductive` questions.

Comment: If you are particularly curious, SO doesn't like OP's to go back disappointed. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell?rq=1

Comment: Yes it is suitable for beginner. Everyone was once beginner when they try to learn something new. Also, SO is not suitable for this kind of question as it is very very subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Haskell is a suitable language for a beginner. In some ways it's easier to learn a functional programming language like Haskell if you haven't been steeped in the Object-0riented tradition. Since you're relatively inexperienced as a programmer, you're still learning the basics of how to analyse a problem and break it down into a series of definitions/steps, and how to debug; those skills are transferrable.

You will find Haskell very different from C and Java. But learning a functional programming will help you see different ways of looking at a problem. Even if you never program in Haskell professionally, knowing a functional programming language will make you a better Java or C programmer. And it seems that functional programming is the wave of the future, so it's a good skill to have.

You will find the Haskell community to be one of the friendliest and most helpful programming communities around (user2339071's reaction notwithstanding). So feel free to ask questions. Stack Overflow is not the best place for questions that require an opinion, but it's great when you have a piece of code you need help with.