# Haskell type is not treated the same when obtained from the current signature or from another function return type

Tags: haskell, types

I started learning Haskell following the recommandations in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016986/1027706).
So I am just implementing easy list functions, and I stumble onto a difference in the compiler behavior I cannot explain to myself :

```
-- Impl 1
elementAt :: (Integral b) => [a] -> b -> a
elementAt xs id = xs !! (fromIntegral(id-1))

-- Impl 2
elementAt' :: (Num b) => [a] -> b -> a
elementAt' xs id = xs !! (id-1)
```

With following signatures :

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

I get an error only for the second implementation, `elementAt'`.

```
Could not deduce (b ~ Int)
from the context (Num b)
```

If I understand correctly, it means that the operator (!!) is expecting an **Int** instance as its second argument (as seen from the signature), but we only guarantee that the provided parameter is conforming to the **Num** typeclass (inferred from `elemenAt'` signature), which is wider than **Int**.

With that in mind, I do not understand why the first implementation actually works, knowing that `fromIntegral` also returns an value that is only conforming to the **Num** typeclass.

Comment: Note that `id` is not a great variable name, being already a standard identifier for the identity function. There's nothing wrong with just `i`.

Comment: When a function returns a `Num a` value, what it's really saying is that "Whatever `Num a` type you need from me, I can provide it." When a function takes a `Num a` value as an argument, really it's saying, "You can give me any `Num a` value and in the most difficult of situations I will know what to do to work it all out." That means that when you take a `Num a` argument, it is *your* responsibility to work it out. When you call a function that returns a `Num a` value, it is *its* responsibility to work it out.

Comment: @kqr Thanks, the first concept (regarding a function returning a `Num a` that could actually return something different depending on the calling context), is what confused me, probably because of my C and C++ background. It has something "templates with return type deduction" to it !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fromIntegral` returns *any* instance of the `Num` class. I.e., whatever instance you require, it'll know how to produce it. That's the idea of a type variable, it's basically an extra compile-time argument which the caller of the function gets to choose. That's why `elemAt` works: the compiler knows we need `Int`, so it tells `fromIntegral`, which then knows what to do.

However, consequently, if *you* define a function with signature `Num b => ...`, you also need to allow the caller put in any type of their choice for `b`, provided it's in the `Num` class. In this case, you do *not* get to ask for the particular instance `Int` but need to take whatever the caller gives you. That's the difference.

In fact, `Num b => [a] -> b -> a` is not a signature for which you could validly define this function. How would you index a list by a complex number, or even an infinitely-dimensional matrix or whatever? What you could do is `Integral b => [a] -> b -> a`.

Comment: I totally agree with your remark regarding signatures : only the first signature makes sense. The second signature is here just for my educational purpose, allowing me to illustrate the orthogonal problem I stumbled upon.