# Haskell to parse XML document

Tags: haskell

I am actually new to haskell. Trying to run this code:

Return the tag name of a XML element

```
getName :: Content -> Name
getName (CElem (Elem nme atts cs)) = nme
```

I've got the following error:

```
Expecting one more argument to `Content'
    In the type signature for `getName': getName :: Content -> Name
```

could you please help me to fix it.

Comment: What library are you using?  Can you provide more information on your specific problem?

Comment: I am using HaXML 1.13.3 and Haskell compiler GHC7.6.3.

Comment: *Hint:* [`Content`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.23.3/docs/Text-XML-HaXml-Types.html#t:Content) is not a type, but a type *constructor*. So as error message suggests, you need to pass one argument to `Content`, e.g. `Content i`.

Comment: What happens if you remove the type signature?  Does it compile?  If so, can you examine the type in GHCi?

Answer (score 2):

There are several problem with the code you posted, all of which can be seen by looking at the types alone. Here is the relevant type information from the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml-1.24.1/docs/Text-XML-HaXml-Types.html#t%3aContent):

```
data Content i = CElem (Element i) i
               | CString Bool CharData i
               | CRef Reference i
               | CMisc Misc i
               deriving Show

data Element i = Elem QName [Attribute] [Content i] deriving (Eq, Show)

data QName = N  Name
           | QN Namespace Name 
           deriving (Eq,Show)

data Reference = RefEntity EntityRef
               | RefChar CharRef
               deriving (Eq,Show)
type EntityRef    = Name
```

Here are your problems with the posted code:

1. The type `Content` has kind `* -> *`, that is, `Content` is a *type constructor* which takes a type parameter as an argument and returns a type. You can't pass a partially applied type (`Content`) as a value to a function, which means your `getName` function should have the signature

   ```
   getName :: Content i -> Name
   ```
2. Your pattern match on `CElem` only has one argument, but you can see from its definition above that it takes *two*. Since you are only using one of the constructor values, we can replace the others with `_`. So far, we have this:

   ```
   getName :: Content i -> Name
   getName (CElem (Elem nme _ _) _) = nme
   ```
3. The first argument of the `Elem` constructor has type `QName`, but your signature suggests you want to return something of type `Name`. This means we can't just return `nme`. Instead, we need to pattern match again on the `N` constructor to pull out the name:

   ```
   getName :: Content i -> Name
   getName (CElem (Elem (N nme) _ _) _) = nme
   ```

While the final definition should compile, you'll likely get runtime errors due to a *refutable pattern match*. This means you will try to match a value against a pattern, but the pattern is not found. For example, the first argument of `Elem` has *type* `QName`, but could instead be constructed using the `QN` constructor. Thus it would be better if we add a case for that constructor:

```
getName (CElem (Elem (QN _ nme) _ _) _) = nme
```

Similarly, you should consider all of the other possibilities for a refutable pattern match: the `Elem` constructor is fine; its type `Element i` only has one constructor. The type `Content i` has multiple constructors. The `CString` constructor doesn't have an obviously-derivable value of type `Name`, so we'll ignore it for now. `CRef` does, so we'll add a case for it:

```
 getName (CRef (RefEntity nme) _) = nme
```

The other constructor for `Reference` doesn't have a name, so we ignore it. I'll leave `CMisc` up to you.

```
 This means that the final definition of `getName` should looks something like this:

 getName :: Content i -> Name
 getName (CElem (Elem (N nme) _ _) _) = nme
 getName (CElem (Elem (QN _ nme) _ _) _) = nme
 getName (CRef (RefEntity nme) _) = nme
 -- maybe add a case for CMisc here
 getName _ = error "Content constructor doesn't have a Name!"
```

Comment: Now that I've solved your problem, let me address some other issues. First, these are all very basic Haskell techniques, which indicates you need to read a tutorial before going any further (or asking more questions on SO). You can find a plethora [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell).

Comment: Simplicity aside, you question has other glaring issues which nearly got it closed. It is very difficult to diagnose compile errors without a *compiling*, *minimal example*. For example, you didn't even mention you used `HaXML` in the original question, and I still had to search through it to find the relevant type information. If you had included the import statement (i.e. made your code compile) it would be more likely to get answers in the future. You can find more information about asking good questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.