# Haskell Applicative instance clarification

Tags: haskell

I have trouble in understanding the following Applicative instance. Can someone explain me what Applicative do(in this case) and how it can be used? Or write it less obfuscated? Thanks!

```
newtype Parser a = P { getParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) }

instance Applicative Parser where
    pure = success

    P p <*> P p' = P $ \s -> case p s of
        Just (f, s') -> fmap (applyToFirst f) $ p' s'
        Nothing      -> Nothing

{-|
    Applies a function to the first component of a pair.
-}
applyToFirst :: (a -> b) -> (a, c) -> (b, c)
applyToFirst f (x, y) = (f x, y)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell)

Comment: What's "obfuscated" in the code you wrote? It's pretty clear.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I don't understand how it's a duplicate.

Comment: @TomEllis I hardly see value in explaining every single possible instance of `Applicative` on SO.

Comment: [`DerivingVia`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia): `newtype Parser a = P { getParser :: String -> Maybe (a, String) } deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Monad, MonadPlus, MonadFix, MonadFail, MonadThrow, MonadState String)`

Comment: Try to understand `Applicative` instances in terms of the `liftA2` method, rather than `(<*>) = liftA2 ($)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the following equivalent code makes it more clear what's going on?

```
instance Applicative Parser where
    pure v = P (\s -> Just (v, s))

    P p <*> P p' = P $ \s -> case p s of
        Just (f, s') -> case p' s' of
          Just (v, s'') -> Just (f v, s'')
          Nothing -> Nothing
        Nothing      -> Nothing
```

Comment: Indeed, the `fmap` and `applyToFirst` do not made the code clearer than your expanded version, especially because `fmap` is used on another functor.

Answer (score 1):

Combining two parsers with `<*>` gives you new parser.  Given an input string, the new parser runs the first parser returning a result and the unparsed remainder of the string.  The remainder of the string is given to the second parser returning a result and unparsed remainder.  Then the two results are combined.  If either parser fails the result is failure.