# Parse error on input 'let'

Tags: haskell

The code takes a quadtree and inserts a rectangle. However I get a parse error on the let statment. I want to call the function newExtent without having to add all the arguments. So `newExtent TopLeft` instead of having to call `newExtent TopLeft extent rectangle`. How do I make it work?

```
    insert :: QuadTree -> Rectangle -> QuadTree
insert (Qt extent horizontal vertical qTL qTR qBL qBR) rectangle    
  | quadPart extent rectangle == VerLine = Qt extent horizontal (rectangle:vertical) qTL qTR qBL qBR
  | quadPart extent rectangle == HorLine = Qt extent (rectangle:horizontal) vertical qTL qTR qBL qBR
  | quadPart extent rectangle == TopLeft && qTL == EmptyQuadTree = Qt extent horizontal vertical (newExtent TopLeft) qTR qBL qBR
  | quadPart extent rectangle == TopLeft = Qt extent horizontal vertical (insert qTL rectangle) qTR qBL qBR 
  | quadPart extent rectangle == TopRight && qTR == EmptyQuadTree = Qt extent horizontal vertical qTL (newExtent TopRight) qBL qBR 
  | quadPart extent rectangle == TopRight = Qt extent horizontal vertical qTL (insert qTR rectangle) qBL qBR
  | quadPart extent rectangle == BottomLeft && qBL == EmptyQuadTree = Qt extent horizontal vertical qTL qTR (newExtent BottomLeft) qBR
  | quadPart extent rectangle == BottomLeft = Qt extent horizontal vertical qTL qTR (insert qBL rectangle) qBR
  | quadPart extent rectangle == BottomRight && qBR == EmptyQuadTree = Qt extent horizontal vertical qTL qTR qBL (newExtent BottomRight)
  | otherwise = Qt extent horizontal vertical qTL qTR qBL (insert qBR rectangle)

  let (Rect eL eT eR eB) = extent

  in  newExtent :: TreeParts -> Rectangle -> Rectangle -> QuadTree
      newExtent part (Rect eL eT eR eB) rectangle
            | part == TopLeft = insert (emptyQtree (Rect eL eT ((eL + eR) `div` 2) ((eT + eB) `div` 2))) rectangle
            | part == TopRight = insert (emptyQtree (Rect ((eL + eR) `div` 2) eT eR ((eT + eB) `div` 2))) rectangle
            | part == BottomLeft = insert (emptyQtree (Rect eL ((eT + eB) `div` 2) ((eL + eR) `div` 2) eB)) rectangle
            | part == BottomRight = insert (emptyQtree (Rect ((eL + eR) `div` 2) ((eT + eB) `div` 2) eR eB)) rectangle
```

Comment: *Please* read a [Haskell tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016986/925978). You cannot put a type signature in a `let` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but I still get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't indent the type signature of insert
2. You don't define functions in the expression after `in`. A let
   statement allows you do define things you can then use in the
   expression after `in` and only there. In this case a `where` statement would probably be easier. In constrast to the let statement here you define things after the definition of a function and you can use them in the function which seems like what you are trying to do. So try replacing your let block by

   ```
   where (Rect eL eT eR eB) = extent
         newExtent part
             | part == TopLeft = insert (emptyQtree (Rect eL eT ((eL + eR) `div` 2) ((eT + eB) `div` 2))) rectangle
             | part == TopRight = insert (emptyQtree (Rect ((eL + eR) `div` 2) eT eR ((eT + eB) `div` 2))) rectangle
             | part == BottomLeft = insert (emptyQtree (Rect eL ((eT + eB) `div` 2) ((eL + eR) `div` 2) eB)) rectangle
             | part == BottomRight = insert (emptyQtree (Rect ((eL + eR) `div` 2) ((eT + eB) `div` 2) eR eB)) rectangle
   ```

Comment: Thanks! However it is still doesn't work. I still have to call newExtent with `newExtent TopLeft extent rectangle`, isn't there a way to fix it so `newExtent TopLeft`?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that part from your question, updated my answer.

Comment: Instead of pattern matching on extent in the where clause you could also just pattern match in the main function definition directly.