# Haskell function returning Integer

Tags: haskell

How do I write a function that returns everything to Integer?

i.e

`f True = 1`
 `f False =0`
 `f 1 = 1`
 `f 2.30 = 2`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell)

Comment: There exists the function `toInteger` that can convert any `Integral a => a` value to an `Integer`, but there is no way to convert any possible type to an `Integer`.  You could write your own `ToInteger` typeclass, then add implementations for `Int`, `Bool`, `Float`, `Double`, etc, but no such thing exists already in Haskell.

Comment: What should `f my_function` return? What about `f [1,2,3]`? What does `f (print 5)` return?

Comment: @David, Getting started is a good place to review, but this question is not a duplicate of that by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only functions of type `a -> Integer` will be constant functions. This is a *free theorem* guaranteed by the parametricity of the type (modulo some fudging because of some unsound corners of Haskell).

Here's an example of such a function:

```
f :: a -> Integer
f _ = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this in general, and it's not at all advisable, but the cases you mention, and some others, can be obtained using an ugly hack:

```
f :: Enum n => n -> Integer
f x = toInteger (fromEnum x)
```

As a general rule, it's best to simply pretend that the `Enum` class does not exist, because it is extremely badly designed and some of its instances are badly behaved.

Comment: Note that this will even break for `Integer` itself if the numbers are larger than what fits in an `Int`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, what part of inadvisable ugly hack didn't you understand :-? You can "fix" that with a rewrite rule, probably, or some horrifying `OverlappingInstances` trick.

Comment: I understood perfectly, I just thought it needed a bit of evidence. Incidentally I recall someone recently complaining about `realToFrac :: Double -> Double`, which *does* have a rewrite rule which changes semantics depending on your optimization level.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I tend to see all such functions and their rewrite rules (including even the ubiquitous `fromIntegral`) as shady.