# First experience with monads (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, monads

I apologize for the subject being unclear. I'm doing Haskell 99 as a beginner, and have encountered the concept of monad first time in my life in [the solution to 67A](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/67A). The part of the problem I'm struggling with is to define a function `stringToTree` that translates sequences like `a(b,c)` to a `Tree`: `Branch a (Branch b Empty Empty) (Branch c Empty Empty)`.

I have tried several "soft" introductions to monads, and failed like many others. I hope by understanding this solution will finally lead me in-door, so I decided to give it a shot here.

#### Questions

1. Would anyone briefly explain what the function `stringToTree :: (Monad m) => String -> m (Tree Char)` defined in the solution? To make this question self-contained, I copied the code from there

```
stringToTree :: (Monad m) => String -> m (Tree Char)
stringToTree "" = return Empty
stringToTree [x] = return $ Branch x Empty Empty
stringToTree str = tfs str >>= \ ("", t) -> return t
    where tfs a@(x:xs) | x == ',' || x == ')' = return (a, Empty)
          tfs (x:y:xs)
                | y == ',' || y == ')' = return (y:xs, Branch x Empty Empty)
                | y == '(' = do (',':xs', l) <- tfs xs
                                (')':xs'', r) <- tfs xs'
                                return $ (xs'', Branch x l r)
          tfs _ = fail "bad parse"
```

2. Why is `monad` useful here? I hope to see how monads largely reduce the difficulties, of course only after one understands it, while defining this function.

Comment: It looks like they are mainly using `Monad` for `fail` (which is being moved to its own class anyhow). My personal preference would be to use the signature `stringToTree :: String -> Maybe (Tree Char)` which I find more informative in its concreteness.  Thankfully `Maybe` is a monad so there is no change to the code necessary.

Comment: @luqui Is `fail` even meant to be used explicitly? I thought it was primarily use in desugaring `do` blocks to handle pattern-match failures. Are `Except` (and/or `Lift`?) preferred for reporting errors?

Comment: This is a bad example for monads. `fail` isn't actually in the monad class anymore. The correct class-constrained signature would be `Alternative m => String -> m (Tree Char)` (but then you need to either turn on the `-XApplicativeDo` extension or reformulate the `do` block to applicative operators yourself). But I agree with Luke that concrete `Maybe` makes more sense as the result monad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the definition lets the caller choose which monad to use. This lets us customize how we deal with failure. For example, we can use `Maybe`:

```
>>> stringToTree "" :: Maybe (Tree Char)
Just Empty
>>> stringToTree "9 +" :: Maybe (Tree Char)
Nothing
```

or `[]`:

```
>>> stringToTree "" :: [Tree Char]
[Empty]
>>> stringToTree "9 +" :: [Tree Char]
[]
```

The code itself makes no assumptions about *which* monad is used; it only uses `>>=`, `return`, and `fail` for working with the results of recursive calls.

Making the type `String -> Tree Char` would indicate that failure simply cannot happen; *every* string has to produce a valid `Tree Char` value (or we raise a runtime error, which is something you should strive to avoid in Haskell).

Note, though, that not all monads provide a definition of `fail` that avoids runtime errors.

```
>>> stringToTree "" :: Either () (Tree Char)
Right Empty
>>> stringToTree "9 +" :: Either () (Tree Char)
*** Exception: bad parse
```

Comment: The answer is .. still overwhelming. I'm actually following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell?rq=1). Maybe I should get back after I finish reading the 14th chapter of "Real World Haskell". That being said, at least I understood something in your answer: the use of monads here is to return an error if needed.

Comment: Wait.. probably not exactly. I remembered doing lots of exercise where I included a function e.g. `factorial :: Int -> Int` and something like `factorial (-1) = error "input number should be positive"` works! I did not use any monads here..

Comment: `error` produces a run-time error, rather than signaling in your code that the operation failed. We call a function that can raise a run-time error a *partial* function, since it isn't really defined for all its arguments; `factorial (-1)` isn't defined, since it doesn't actually return an `Int`. `factorial' :: Int -> Maybe Int`, however, *can* be defined for all `Int` values; e.g., `factorial' 5 == Just 120`, and `factorial' (-1) == Nothing`. This forces you, the programmer to acknowledge and deal with possible errors, rather than letting your program fail when run.

Answer (score 1):

Why monads are useful? Some broader context.

Monads are a *unification* of several things that traditionally have been handled by different language mechanisms. Among them are

- Sequencing (like in IO or State)
- Non-determinism (like in the list monad)
- Failure and exceptions (like in Maybe)
- Saving and resuming computations (the Cont monad, which you will encounter in the future)
- Atomic transactions (the STM monad)
- Parsing (Parsec and its relatives)

By "unification" I mean the kind of thing that Newton did when he unified the laws of physics for things on Earth and things in the sky, or when Maxwell unified electricity and magnetism into the electromagnetic field; its a deeper underlying theory which yields all of the above as special cases and shows how you can create new things along the same lines.

In monads the type of the "bind" function `(>>=)` is the central equation in the theory; it describes how one step in the computation can be daisy-chained on to the next. `return` is the primitive null step. This is something you get used to in Haskell; everything has some kind of zero or null or identity value. `fail` is a step that doesn't work, which (as @chepner says in a comment elsewhere) is needed for partial functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very excited to get there (to be able to fully understand and appreciate) soon.