# First Haskell program not launching

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I have written my first Haskell code in Visual Studio Code. I want to implement list of lists so I started with simple list.

```
module Main where
import System.Environment
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

main :: IO ()
main =  do
    let lostNumbers = [4,8,15,16,23,42]
```

When I try to launch my program I get:

[image]

How do I declare a list of lists in Haskell? Or at least just a simple list?

EDIT:
I have found topic that discuss on where to look for Haskell tutorials:
[Getting started with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell?rq=1)

Hope it will help someone

Comment: You don't do anything in your `do`. The last statement of a `do` block can not be a `let`, since you simply define a local variable, and then throw it away, making the `do` block non-sensical.

Comment: Thank you. Havent realised that since I am completely new :)

Comment: please do not post pictures of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong. The last line of your do block is that let expression and not a value of type `IO ()`

Update it to, for example:

```hs
lostNumbers = [4,8,15,16,23,42] 

main :: IO ()
main =  do
    print lostNumbers
```

If the `let` is important to you..

```hs
main :: IO ()
main =  do
    let lostNumbers = [4,8,15,16,23,42] in print lostNumbers
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I am new. It is very hard to find any good tutorials about Haskell. Not even how to declare an array, I couldnt find it anywhere. Is it dead language, or I was looking in wrong places or what? :)

Comment: There are excellent books for learning Haskell. For example https://haskellbook.com/

Comment: [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) is by far the best for a Haskell beginner in my opinion. There's also the excellent [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell)

Comment: haskellbook.com is paid, but there are 95 pages for free so thanks :)

Comment: Learn You a Haskell sure does cater more to beginner sensibilities. I'm not sure it's a better book for beginners than Haskell Book though.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your code, I get this error:

```
main.hs:8:5: error:
    The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      let lostNumbers = [4, ....]
```

So the last statement of the `do` block must be an expression such as

```
print lostNumbers
```

Comment: Thank you, maybe you also now how to declare array of arrays? I want to have array in which every element can be array of different sizes

Comment: myListOfLists = [[1,2], [3,4]]

Answer (score 0):

your code have unused imports as a starting point to write haskell code, I modified your code to

```
lostNumbers :: [Integer]
lostNumbers = [4,8,15,16,23,42]
```

or, in case you would like to use module keyword, you have to be careful for spaces for example

```
module Main where
    lostNumbers :: [Integer]
    lostNumbers = [4,8,15,16,23,42]
```