# If length is 2 do Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm not sure how to work around the If-Else, for example:

```
function str = if ((length str) = 2) then (....)
```

In java we would:

```
if (str.length =2){
    str = "2"}
else { str ="1"}
```

How do you write it in haskell?

Comment: What do you mean by "work around the if-Else"? It is very unclear what your example is supposed to illustrate.

Comment: see example in Java

Comment: It's still not a good illustration since you're using assignments. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? (You should probably take a look at the tips at [Getting started with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell). Trying to program in Haskell while thinking in Java is only going to be frustrating.)

Comment: you question is a bit confusing because: In your Haskell example you don't include a `else` branch, but in Haskell you *need* one. On the other hand in Java you *include* the `else` branch but you would not need it there.

Comment: Also (just in Java?) you want to use `==` to compare to values for *equality* - I think your Java-code would not work either (sorry never programmed in Java but you need `;` also right?).

Comment: Note that assigning to parameters does nothing in Java. That is, `void foo(String str) { if (str.length == 2) { str = "2"; } else { str = "1"; } }` (which I assume is the code you meant because your code is incomplete and contains syntax errors) is exactly equivalent to `void foo(String str) { /* do nothing */ }`. The Haskell equivalent of that would be `foo _ = ()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Guards:

```
fnc :: String -> String
fnc s | length s == 2 = ...
      | otherwise = ...
```

[More to Guards](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards)

---

Or conditions

```
fnc :: String -> String
fnc s = if length s == 2 then ... else ...
```

---

It is also possible to use pattern matching, more [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching).

There are several ways to achieve conditions (e.g. `case of`) in Haskell.

Comment: Yeah you are right! Had it before like `String -> Int` and changed it wrong.