# Parse error, possiby identation or mismatch brackets

Tags: haskell, ghc, hlint

I'm writing a program in haskell but I doesn't get rid of an error:

```
mountTree :: [Char] -> FilePath -> Int -> Either IO [FilePath] String
mountTree promatiList toScan 0 = do
    b <- getDirectoryContests(initial)
    return mountTree getDirectoryContests initial 1

mountTree [] [] 0 = do
    print "Nothing to delete"

mountTree primariList toScan dir = do
    primariList <- getDirectoryContests(primariList)
    where
        if length(primariList) == dir then
            return "Done" 
        else
            toScan[leaf] = []
            if dir > 0 then
                toScan ++ mapM_ (++) mountTree(initialDir, toScan(leaf), dir + 1)
            else    
                let value = if length(toScan) == 0 
                    then
                        pop primariList
                        map (primariList, toScan(leaf), 0)
                    else
                        if length(toScan[leaf]) == initialDir then
                            leaf + 1
                            mountTree(initialDir, toScan(tmpLeaf), (dir + 1))
                        else
                            mountTree(primariList, toScan(dir + 1), (dir + 1))


main :: IO ()
main done = print done
main = do
    initialPath <- getLine
    tree = mountTree(intitialPath)
    mapM_ (\x -> x) tree
```

Where are the error an how I can get rid of it error?

I've search but not found an error, including the use of pipe operator. FOrget the algorithn and focus on the parse error.

Comment: It is rather difficult to pinpoint "the error" because most of this is totally wrong, but perhaps the most obvious one is your use of `if`. In Haskell, you cannot say `if condition then doThis; doThat else doOther; doSomethingDifferent`. You need exactly one expression after `then` and exactly one expression after `else`. (Note, expression, not "statement").

Comment: Or maybe it is the incorrect syntax of `where`. After `where`, you need a list of declarations, not an expression, and `if` is an expression.

Comment: There're so many issues here I was unable to write an answer. I think you are very far from working code -- there's almost nothing that can be salvaged. I'd suggest to start from solving easier exercises, getting accustomed with the basic syntax and semantics first. For instance `f x y g(z)` is equivalent to `f x y g z`, calling `f` with 4 arguments. Also, `f(x,y,z)` is often wrong, and should be `f x y z`. In Haskell you can't mutate a variable as you try to do with `a[..]=..` and `pop array`. `map` and `mapM_` can not be used in that way. `leaf + 1` again attempts mutation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parse error is the result of the line:

```
let value = if length(toScan) == 0
```

Because of where this appears, the compiler is expecting a `let ... in ...` expression, so it is scanning for the `in` keyword when the `main` definition appears in the first column and prematurely ends the indented block.

Often, this kind of error is the result of an indentation mistake or an extra parenthesis, which is why the error message says what it does.

One way to fix this parse error is to delete the text `"let value = "`.  That will fix this particular parse error, but you will get additional errors:  one about using `if...then...else` syntax in a pattern, and another about an unexpected `if` expression in a function application.

It's possible to fix these errors, too, to get a version that will at least parse completely (and start complaining about undefined variables).  I've attached it below.

However, two people in the comments have already shared their opinion that this code cannot be made to work, and I have to agree with them.  With some programming languages, you can write some draft code that's full of errors and let the compiler/interpreter error messages "guide" you to working code, and for those languages, this approach might be a good way to learn the language.

For a variety of reasons, this doesn't work well for Haskell.  When you write:

```
leaf + 1
mountTree(initialDir, toScan(tmpLeaf), (dir + 1))
```

the compiler "understands this", but while *you* think you're incrementing `leaf` and then calling `mountTree` with three arguments, the compiler thinks you're adding `leaf` to the function `1` applied to two arguments, `mountTree` and a three-element tuple.  As it searches for a way to turn `1` into a two-argument function, you're likely to get a compiler error message about a missing `Num` instance for a really weird function type.  The compiler can't provide you with a useful error message because you and the compiler are too far from agreeing on what this code should mean.

Your program has many similar errors, with nearly every line containing code that's "valid" but means something completely different from what you intended.  You will find the process of trying to turn this program into working code a frustrating and demoralizing experience.

It's probably better to learn Haskell with a more bottom-up approach, starting with really simple "programs" that don't really *do* anything.  Instead of trying to write a full program to perform a recursive operation on a filesystem, you should maybe be writing a function to extract the first `n` elements from a list, the sort of programs you find in very basic tutorials.  I'd suggest working through some of the beginner materials mentioned in the answers to [Getting started with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1012573/7203016).  Note that this question has one, extremely highly voted answer, but there are good tips in some of the other answers, too, so look through those as well.

Anyway, here's the version of the program that I got to parse okay, though -- as I said above -- I think getting it from here to actually working code will be very difficult:

```
mountTree promatiList toScan 0 = do
    b <- getDirectoryContests(initial)
    return mountTree getDirectoryContests initial 1

mountTree [] [] 0 = do
    print "Nothing to delete"

mountTree primariList toScan dir = do
    primariList <- getDirectoryContests(primariList)
    if length(primariList) == dir then
        return "Done"
    else do
        let toScan[leaf] = []
        if dir > 0 then
            toScan ++ mapM_ (++) mountTree(initialDir, toScan(leaf), dir + 1)
        else
            if length(toScan) == 0
            then
                pop primariList
                map (primariList, toScan(leaf), 0)
            else
                if length(toScan[leaf]) == initialDir then
                    leaf + 1
                    mountTree(initialDir, toScan(tmpLeaf), (dir + 1))
                else
                    mountTree(primariList, toScan(dir + 1), (dir + 1))

main :: IO ()
main done = print done
main = do
    initialPath <- getLine
    let tree = mountTree(intitialPath)
    mapM_ (\x -> x) tree
```

Comment: On the following paste I gain a parse error on compilation.
What could be happen? Ohh, I fixed the issues mentioned by you.

https://pastebin.com/HN9gMFT3

Comment: Sorry for the lack of upvote. My reputation doesn't permit it yet.

Comment: In your original code and your pastebin, you have `where if ...then ...` which isn't syntactically valid.  The `where` keyword is used to introduce local definitions (e.g., functions, constants) for the use of the previous expression, and an `if` statement isn't a valid definition.