# Haskell colon within the zip function

Tags: haskell

I struggle understanding this Haskell function. I know what it does superficially, but I'm unsure of how it achieves this functionality.

```
zip (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : zip xs ys 
zip xs ys = [ ]
```

**What I think:**

1. `zip` is the name of the function.
2. `zip` takes 2 parameters. (I believe currying is not important here).
3. The parammeters are `(x:xs)` and `(y:ys)`
4. `zip` returns a list of a tuple type `(x,y)`.

Now I don't quite understand the parameters

```
(x:xs) (y:ys)
```

The colon appends something to the start of a list (returning the list), so why do we append something to the lists we want to zip? What are `x` and `y` in the function definition?

The right side seems pretty obvious: We insert(0) the tuple (x,y) to a list of tuples returned by zip.

```
(x,y) : zip xs ys
```

Now `zip xs ys = [ ]` why would we always want an empty list if we just pass 2 lists?

Could you explain how the following call to `zip` would be evaluation:

```
zip [5,7,9] [1,3,5,11]
```

Comment: The keyword you are looking for to learn about the `:` on the left side is "pattern matching". This is a recursive definition, in which the second equation (which is only used if the first one doesn't match the arguments) is the base case. Compare with [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482697/a-newbie-to-haskell-help/4482764#4482764) (only note that the base case comes first there, which also works).

Comment: thank you, that also helped

Comment: To clarify your assumptions 1. - 4. are all correct, and if you are in doubt about the type of the function you can fire up ghci and type `Prelude>:t zip` to find out about it's type, this works for any function as long it is in scope, so if you have a function that is not in `Prelude` say `splitOn` you have to do `Prelude> import Data.List.Split` (that's where splitOn comes from) in order to get it in scope. For operators you have to wrap them in parens `Prelude> :t (/=)`.

Comment: @JonasShinaniganz remember to accept an answer if you find one of them complete and accurate. Good questions!

Answer (score 6):

The `(x:xs)` on the left hand side of equations is a *pattern*. It *deconstructs* an argument.

The `(x:xs)` on the right hand side of equations is an *expression*. It *constructs* a value.

```
zip (x:xs) (y:ys) =
```

means, `zip` is a function, expecting two arguments, both are expected to be non-empty lists.

```
                      (x,y) : zip xs ys
```

this constructs an output value; its head is `(x,y)` and its tail is the result of calling `zip xs ys`:

```
       [ x1,   x2, x3, x4, ....
       [ y1,   y2, y3, y4, ....
      --------------------------
    [ (x1,y1) , ................
```

Trying to call `zip (5,7,9) (1,3,5,11)` won't work (will cause a compile-time type-mismatch error), because the first rgument here is a triple, and the second - 4-tuple; these are *not* lists. Lists are of varying sizes, but tuples have fixed sizes. The correct call is thus `zip [5,7,9] [1,3,5,11]`. You can see how it is reduced to a value (i.e. what result is describes), by substituting the numbers to the above scheme's `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, etc.

When one of the lists is exhausted, the call will be `zip [] [11]`. The above equation won't match this situation. Fortunately, you have another equation,

```
zip xs ys =
```

which uses variables as patterns. This is an example of an *irrefutable* pattern; it always succeeds. So, whatever the two arguments are, first will be henceforth known as `xs`, second - `ys`, and the right hand side of the equation

```
               [ ]
```

will be entered, that shows that the value `[]` will be produced, always. The effect of it is that when the list arguments to `zip` are of different lengths, the extra elements of the longer list are ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Let's work with a simpler example:

```
head (x:xs) = x
```

The thing to realize is that the list `[1,2,3]` is shorthand for `1:2:3:[]`, which is again shorthand for `1:(2:(3:[]))` because `(:)` is right-associative.  So taking

```
head [1,2,3]
```

that's the same as

```
head (1:(2:(3:[])))
```

And now we can see how the pattern resembles the input.

```
head (1:(2:(3:[])))
      ^  ^^^^^^^^
head (x:   xs     )
```

So `x` will be `1` and `xs` will be `2:(3:[])`, in other words `[2,3]`.

---

Expounding a little about pattern matching.  The first equation for `zip`

```
zip (x:xs) (y:ys) = ...
```

matches when both lists have at least one element (because empty lists are not of the form `a:b`). The second equation

```
zip xs ys = ...
```

matches any arguments whatsoever, provided the first equation did not match (and that they are the right type, since Haskell is statically typed).

Comment: really nice! You said: "(because empty lists are not of the form a:b)" why does the empty list not match a:b? [] = []:[] should match a:b with a=[], b=[]?

Comment: `[]:[]` is `[ [] ]` - a list of one element (which is an empty list). its head element is `[]`, and its tail is `[]` - i.e., no more elements there.